# Software Unavailable in 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, synapse

Lots of software that were downloadable in the previous versions of Ubuntu (like 11.10, 12.04 LTS, 13.10) seem not to be available in 14.04 LTS. Like, Synapse is not available, or GnomeBaker. There maybe a lot more but I have not explored further. Using Ubuntu without Synapse is frustrating, since I have got so much used to it. So, how can I get Synapse in my computer? Should I revert to my older 12.04 LTS version?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes programs are dropped in which case you can downgrade to 12.04 as you suggested or try installing another way like using the old repos package file, seeing if the program devs have their own up to date repos, or installing from source.

## Synapse:

You can download the 13.10 version from http#://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/synapse and install it. My understanding is it has a bug involving Unity/Gnome3 which is why Synapse hasn't yet been included. Some people say this version works fine in 14.04. Seems to work fine to me, but I've never used it before now.

**Screen Rec of the steps (MP4 1MB):** https://copy.com/stxCHYmU6luy

### Steps:

**Step #1**

Open your web browser, go to [this page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/synapse)", click the appropriate package version for your system [*Eg: i386 for 32bit or amd64 for 64bit.*], and pick a mirror to download from.

**Step #2** (Optional)

In terminal type `sudo apt-get install gdebi`. [My instructions are for **Gdebi**. If you
choose to use Ubuntu Software Center then you will need to adjust my instructions
accordingly. I did it this way because Ubuntu Software Center kept getting stuck. I also happen to prefer Gdebi.]

**Step #3**

Navigate to your user account's download folder, right click on the .deb you downloaded, and from the "open with" options choose "gdebi". Click install.